# Toggle elements which is out side the div

Tags: jquery, toggle

Below elements second hide button is working. if I put the div to the button it is not working. With out giving the id is it possible to do so?

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle").click(function() 
{  
// hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
$(".content", $(this).next()).toggle(); 
});   
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
<input class="toggle" type='button' value='hide'>
</div>
<div>
<div class="content">
Content 1
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<input class="toggle" type='button' value='hide'>
<div>
<div class="content">
Content 2
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle").click(function() 
{  
// hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
      $(this).parent().next("div.content").toggle(); 
});   
});
```

Comment: yes all above answers  working fine if I put div for both button. Thank you very much

Comment: Bleow case it is not working!!!<div class="widget" id="A" >
<strong><div><input type="button" class="toggle" value="Edit" /></div></strong>    
            
            <div style='display:none' class="content">
              Content one
            </div>
</div>
<div class="widget" id="B" >
<strong><div><input type="button" class="toggle" value="Edit" /></div></strong>    
            
            <div style='display:none' class="content">
              Content one
            </div>
</div>
});

Comment: Try my edited answer it will work for the markup you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".content").toggle();
});
```

// or

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".content", $(this).parent().next()).toggle();
});
```

In other words, you need to traverse up one level before getting the next div using `.next()`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HX6Kv/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {  
        // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
        $(this).parents().find(".content").toggle(); 
    });   
});
```

I tried the above it is also working for me when I put a main div for content div